# Firebase when getString doesn't find the field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#getString(java.lang.String)) for DocumentSnapshot.getString() states that it returns:

> Value as a string if a value corresponding to the look up key was
>   present and could be converted to a string; default (if set) or static
>   default value otherwise.

I would like to do a `DocumentSnapshot.getString` for the field `isSomeType` which stores a boolean value and if the `DocumentSnapshot` does not contain the key `isSomeType` then detect that.  What is the static default value that it would return in this case because I would like to check for equality to that value.

For those wondering, I would like one collection to have a field storing a boolean variable declaring its type but don't want to have other documents needing to contain a field just to declare that they're not a certain type.  This way, I can detect whether they declare that they're a certain type or not by checking the field.

Comment: You're asking about Cloud Firestore, but the link you provide is to Firebase Remote Config. The two products are quite different, and for the Cloud Firestore `DocumentSnapshot.getString()` method you'll want to look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getString(java.lang.String)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So then it throws a runtime exception if it's not a String.  Does it do this if the field doesn't exist as well?